# Group by x where y = A and B and C

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table that stores product price information.  It has a column for the product ID, a quantity and a discount. (Users buys 2 gets £1 off, buys 3 gets £2 off etc).

I'd like to pull all products that have specific quantity discounts associated with them.  For example only products that have £5, £10 and £20 off buying 1,2 or 3 respectively.

How can I do that?

I want to group by product ID where there is are three rows that match my criteria - and no other products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested (depends on your schema) but here's the idea:

```
SELECT P.id, count(P.id)
FROM products P
  LEFT JOIN discounts D ON P.id = D.product_id
WHERE
  (D.quantity = 1 AND D.amount = 5)
  OR (D.quantity = 2 AND D.amount = 10)
  OR (D.quantity = 3 AND D.amount = 20)
GROUP BY P.id
HAVING count(P.id) = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the query for SQL Server, there might be a couple tweaks for MySql, but this is the basics.

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE> WHERE ProductId in
(SELECT ProductId
FROM <TABLE>
GROUP BY ProductId
HAVING COUNT(ProductId) = 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for starting me off!  Your query worked, I just had to add some where clause.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ProductID IN
(SELECT ProductId
FROM table
WHERE (qty = X AND price = X) OR (qty = X AND price = X) OR (qty = X AND price = X)
GROUP BY ProductID
HAVING COUNT(ProductID) = 3)

GROUP BY productID
ORDER BY productID, qty
```

This gave me the filtering I needed.  Thank you for starting me off!